# Facebook/Twitter authorization in Android App

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, webview

I use the Facebook sdk to authorize Facebook Account in my code and Twitter4J to authorize Twitter accounts. Using Twitter4J I have to create the webview and change the focus to that and then deal with the response. My problem seems to be that if the user authorizes a Twitter Account and after that finishes tries to authorize a Facebook account, the webview for Facebook continuously loads and stops the user from using the app. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because i turned off cookies for the browser when I made the webview for Twitter. Just made sure to re-enable before done saving the account information.